# How can i display a different color when the cursor is hovered over Navigation rail items on Navigation rail flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am creating a flutter app for desktop and i have used navigation rail for navigating to different screens. All works fine but my use case requires displaying a particular color whenever the cursor is hovered over a particular navigation rail destination. I have been struggling to achieve this because not much regarding 'this' has been mentioned in the documentation. Does anyone have any idea regarding how to achieve this ?
Any help will be highly apprecaited. :D

Just for your reference, here is the code snippet for the same :

```
NavigationRail(
                    leading: Container(
                      height: 100,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          image: AssetImage('images/transparent_logo.png'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    selectedLabelTextStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    // leading: Image(
                    //   image: AssetImage('images/logo.png'),
                    // ),
                    backgroundColor: lightTheme.primary,
                    selectedIndex: global.offlineSelectedNavIndex,
                    onDestinationSelected: (index) {
                      setState(() {
                        global.offlineSelectedNavIndex = index;
                      });
                      switch (index) {
                        case 0:
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/dashboard');
                          global.selectedNavIndex = 0;
                          break;
                        case 1:
                          Navigator.popUntil(
                            context,
                            ModalRoute.withName('/dashboard'),
                          );
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/inventory');
                          global.selectedNavIndex = 1;
                          break;
                        case 2:
                          Navigator.popUntil(
                            context,
                            ModalRoute.withName('/dashboard'),
                          );
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/pos');
                          global.selectedNavIndex = 3;
                          break;
                        case 3:
                          Navigator.popUntil(
                            context,
                            ModalRoute.withName('/dashboard'),
                          );
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/sales');
                          global.selectedNavIndex = 4;
                          break;
                        case 4:
                          appLogOut();
                          SharedService.logout().then(
                            (_) => Navigator.of(context)
                                .pushReplacementNamed('/login'),
                          );
                          global.selectedNavIndex = 0;
                          break;
                        default:
                          Navigator.popUntil(
                            context,
                            ModalRoute.withName('/dashboard'),
                          );
                          global.selectedNavIndex = 0;
                      }
                    },
                    labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
                    destinations: [
                      NavigationRailDestination(
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.bar_chart_outlined,
                        ),
                        selectedIcon: const Icon(
                          Icons.bar_chart_outlined,
                          color: Color(0xffff3838),
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          'DASHBOARD',
                          style: navigationRailTextStyle,
                        ),
                      ),
                      NavigationRailDestination(
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.inventory_2_outlined,
                        ),
                        selectedIcon: const Icon(
                          Icons.inventory_2_outlined,
                          color: Color(0xffff3838),
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          'INVENTORY',
                          style: navigationRailTextStyle,
                        ),
                      ),
                      NavigationRailDestination(
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
                        ),
                        selectedIcon: const Icon(
                          Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
                          color: Color(0xffff3838),
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          'POS',
                          style: navigationRailTextStyle,
                        ),
                      ),
                      NavigationRailDestination(
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.receipt_long_outlined,
                        ),
                        selectedIcon: const Icon(
                          Icons.receipt_long_outlined,
                          color: Color(0xffff3838),
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          'SALES',
                          style: navigationRailTextStyle,
                        ),
                      ),
                      NavigationRailDestination(
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.logout_outlined,
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          'LOGOUT',
                          style: navigationRailTextStyle,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

hover color:

```
RawMaterialButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                  fillColor: Colors.black12,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5, left: 5),
                  onPressed: (){},
                  hoverColor: Colors.black26,
                  elevation: 0,
                  child: Text(
                    'Find',
                    style:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: No, this will not work if i go to some other navigation rail destination. Anyways, thanks for answering.

Comment: did you get any solution for this?, im also having same issue